# How many assembly depth can Autodesk Forge show?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How many assembly depth(level) can Autodesk Forge show?
The attached picture shows 4 levels
mainv8 > x-asiox_4__railbear > linaril700 > Body

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CICK8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit on that. The **[Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/)** will show as many levels as available in the original model - e.g.:

[image]